# Get id of enclosing li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  a HTML structure as follow. I've attached a jquery function to fire when `click me` is clicked. From the function , I need to get the id of the the enclosing `li` element. Is this possible? How?

```
<ul>
<li id="20">
<a href="#">click me </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line inside your click handler:

```
var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id")
```

Comment: What if there is another `li` after this ? Which `li` will it take as the closest?

Comment: Assuming the event handler is attached to (one or more) `a` elements, it will return the one that contains the `a` that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2JW9x/)</kbd>

```
var li_id = $('a').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === 'click me ';
}).parent().attr('id');
```

or

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2JW9x/1)</kbd>

```
var li_id =$('a:contains("click me")').parent().attr('id');
```

---

```
var li_id = $(this).parent().attr("id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('a').click(function () {
   var li = $(this).parent();
   var li_id = li.attr('id');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zugdB/

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M78AT/)

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).parent('li').attr('id'));         
});
```